# docker failed with rancher

Tags: linux, bash, docker, rancher

```
IMAGE_NAME="harbor.infra.yandex.astral-dev.ru/astral-edo/go/astral-ubuntu-builder:v4"

docker pull $IMAGE_NAME
docker volume create edi_operator_pkg

docker run -it --rm \
\-v $(pwd):/mnt \
\-v edi_operator_pkg:/root/go/pkg \
$IMAGE_NAME
```

[Run docker script, and output was:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC7s5.png)

I need to start my docker

Comment: in link i posted photo, why docker connecting to unix:///home/la/.rd/docker.sock, maybee because i used rancher-desctop

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in short, my rancher put the cube config in context/meta and in config.json of docker and the docker-cli  went into the .rd folder with the daemon